# excel bva code to send command to usb printer

Tags: usb, printers

I am trying to use my Epson TM U220 as I did before installing a new PC with WIN 7 64bit and Excel2010, no parallel port. In the past I used this simple code to open cash drawer:

```
Sub drawer_opener()
Open "LPT1" For Output As #1
Print #1, Chr(27) + Chr(112) + Chr(0) + Chr(25) + Chr(250)
Close #1

End Sub
```

Now I am using an adapter parallel-USB but with no response to opening cash drawer commnad after changing "LPT1" to "USB001" in code.
After some web research I found following code that is supposed to work, but it keeps popping error messages for one reason or the other.

I quote thread I found and give all the credit to "Mike"
quote
As you've discovered, that approach won't work on USB printers. Try
the following instead. I've assumed that the USB printer is set up as
your default printer (although it is possible to add code to look for
it if it is not) and of course you'll also need to check that your new
printer obeys the same control codes in the same way as your old one.

Mike

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function OpenPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" _
Alias "OpenPrinterA" (ByVal pPrinterName As String, _
phPrinter As Long, ByVal pDefault As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function StartDocPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" _
Alias "StartDocPrinterA" (ByVal hPrinter As Long, _
ByVal Level As Long, pDocInfo As DOCINFO) As Long
Private Declare Function StartPagePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" _
(ByVal hPrinter As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function WritePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" _
(ByVal hPrinter As Long, pBuf As Any, _
ByVal cdBuf As Long, pcWritten As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ClosePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" _
(ByVal hPrinter As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EndDocPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" _
(ByVal hPrinter As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EndPagePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" _
(ByVal hPrinter As Long) As Long
Private Type DOCINFO
pDocName As String
pOutputFile As String
pDatatype As String
End Type

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim printerHandle As Long, retVal As Long
Dim bytesWritten As Long, lDoc As Long
Dim s1 As String, MyDocInfo As DOCINFO
retVal = OpenPrinter(Printer.DeviceName, printerHandle, 0)
If retVal = 0 Then
MsgBox "Printer Not found"
Exit Sub
End If
MyDocInfo.pDocName = "Any Name"
MyDocInfo.pOutputFile = vbNullString
MyDocInfo.pDatatype = vbNullString
lDoc = StartDocPrinter(printerHandle, 1, MyDocInfo)
Call StartPagePrinter(printerHandle)
s1 = Chr(27) + Chr(112) + Chr(0) + Chr(25) + Chr(250)
retVal = WritePrinter(printerHandle, ByVal s1, _
Len(s1), bytesWritten)
retVal = EndPagePrinter(printerHandle)
retVal = EndDocPrinter(printerHandle)
retVal = ClosePrinter(printerHandle)
End Sub
```

unquote

I kindly request that some expert of you guys would please try the code and see if it just doesnt work for Excel2010, if it is not actually VBA or what is the problem. Also if there is no hope via software (code) solution to send command to Epson printer and I have to install a parallel port in PC and start using a parallel-parallel cable as in the past.

Tks in advance, Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler approach: Share your USB Printer, and then map the printer share to `LPT1:` via `net use`:

```
net use LPT1: \\.\PrinterShareName
```

This way you can try to make your old code work.

Comment: Tks Turbo J, Is it possible that you be a bit more specific. I mean, I think sharing the printer is easy in the Properties window, Should I just write LPT1?. or the whole line: net use LPT1: \\.\PrinterShareName is needed (in this case my printer's name is "ticket", so how would be the correct syntax in the line. Now, How can I send the command?...using my old code in the same way, invoking the LPT1 port to open and so on?

Comment: Hey Turbo J. I finally got help from a systems guy and could finally resolve the issue with this: net use LPT1: \\PCName\\PrinterShareName at the command prompt. Great help from you. Slim and simple. You are my hero. Thanks sooo much!!! Best Regards, Gabriel