# StartDocPrinter WinAPI call fails in VBA

Tags: vba, winapi, printing

**Objective**: Print from string or rich text box to any printer desired, using the Win API functions specified.

**Problem**: Calling StartDocPrinter in VBA Access always returns 0.

**Info**: The code below runs through, without breaking. `OpenPrinter` appears to get a good handle. When `StartDocPrinter` is called, it returns 0.

Using the following code I have tried,

- Saving different info to `dDocInfo` and per @David_Heffernan recommendation, declared DOCINFO properties as Long and set values to 0.

  - When `.pDatatype = vbNullstring`, `GetLastError` returns,

    - Error 124 (invalid level) when `StartDocPrinter parameter Level` = `1`
    - Error 6 (invalid handle) when `StarDocPrinter parameter Level` = `ByVal 1`, though an apparent valid handle shows in hPrinter
  - When `.pDatatype = "RAW"`, `GetLastError` returns 0 regardless.
  - When `.pDatatype = 'vbNullString` and either DOCINFO property is set to a string, `GetLastError` returns 0 regardless.
- Changing the parameters of the WinAPI functions (`ByRef DOCINFO`)
- Checking into access privilege issues. It appears, from other's code, that setting the last `OpenPrinter` parameter to 0 should set the requested access to the printer to be `PRINTER_ACCESS_USE`. Is it possible GetLastError is not returning access denial errors?
- Converting multiple references' code from C++ to VBA, but converting or not including pointers is confusing. Am I not converting `StartDocPrinter(printer, 1, (LPBYTE) &docInfo);` correctly?

**Code:**

Declarations:

```
Type DOCINFO
 pDocName As String
 pOutputFile As String
 pDatatype As String
End Type

Public Declare Function OpenPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias "OpenPrinterA" (ByVal pPrinterName As String, hPrinter As Long, ByVal pDefault As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function StartDocPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias "StartDocPrinterA" (hPrinter As Long, Level As Long, dDocInfo As DOCINFO) As Long
```

Function:

```
Public Function printRawData(sPrinterName As String, lData As String) As Boolean
  Dim bStatus As Boolean, hPrinter As Long, dDocInfo As DOCINFO, lJob As Long, nWritten As Integer

  ' Open a handle to the printer.
  bStatus = OpenPrinter(sPrinterName, hPrinter, 0)
  If bStatus Then
    ' Fill in the structure with info about this "document."
    dDocInfo.pDocName = vbNullString
    dDocInfo.pOutputFile = vbNullString
    dDocInfo.pDatatype = "RAW"

    ' Inform the spooler the document is beginning.
    lJob = StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, dDocInfo) 'Returns 0 :(
    Debug.Print hPrinter, sPrinterName, lJob, GetLastError()

    If lJob > 0 Then
        ' Start a page.
        bStatus = StartPagePrinter(hPrinter)
        If bStatus Then
            ' Send the data to the printer.
            bStatus = WritePrinter(hPrinter, lData, Len(lData), nWritten)
            EndPagePrinter (hPrinter)
        End If
        ' Inform the spooler that the document is ending.
        EndDocPrinter (hPrinter)
    End If
    ' Close the printer handle.
    ClosePrinter (hPrinter)
  End If

  ' Check to see if correct number of bytes were written.
  If Not bStatus Or (nWritten <> Len(lData)) Then
    printRawData = False
  Else
    printRawData = True
  End If
End Function
```

**References/Relevant Questions:**
 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154078 Basis document for this code. *Edit: Found where `ByVal` was missed on a few declarations here.*
 - [Send Raw Data to ZPL Printer using Visual Basic (MS Access 2000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831819/send-raw-data-to-zpl-printer-using-visual-basic-ms-access-2000/12855870) This person seems to use nearly identical code effectively, so why can't I? The answer to this question is written in C++.
 - http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/26184/ The code here is also written in C++ and I am unsure how to convert.
 - http://codingdomain.com/visualbasic/win32api/datatypes/ Guidance I'm using on converting datatypes and pointers, which I don't fully understand.
 - [StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di) returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189135/startdocprinterhprinter-1-di-returns-false) Some code was provided here but no answer. This is where I got idea to give errors provided.
 - [excel bva code to send command to usb printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829178/excel-bva-code-to-send-command-to-usb-printer) I tried this and do not have the required access privileges. I would still like to know how to use the above code correctly, even if this is what I would end up doing.

Comment: Perhaps there's an error in the code that we cannot see

Comment: Added DOCINFO type and declarations for the functions called up to that point, `OpenPrinter` and `StartDocPrinter`.

Comment: Isn't `vbNullString` equal to `""`. I think you need `NULL`. Perhaps easiest by declaring those fields of the record to be `Long` and passing `0`.

Comment: I thought all of the DOCINFO properties could be strings? Some examples in linked documents were `DOCINFO.DataType = "RAW"` and `DOCINFO.DocName = "AAAA"` . Strings throw errors when set to NULL.

Comment: If you declare the values as strings then I don't think you can pass `NULL`. There's a different between `""` and `NULL` in C. The first is a pointer to a single zero char. The second is the null pointer. So, try changing the types if `pDocName` and `pOutputFile` to `LONG` and passing `0`.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154078

Comment: Attempted setting all DOCINFO as Longs and setting values to 0. Causes similar response as when all three DOCINFO properties are set to `vbNullString`.

Comment: @HansPassant my code is nearly a copy and paste from that post. That was where I originally got the idea.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok. My code wasn't copy and paste enough. I just added ByVal to both hPrinter and Level and the lJob returned 16. Bombed on StartPagePrinter, but probably for similar reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @HansPassant's link to the MS KB, I discovered the error in my code. The declaration of the StartDocPrinter function was missing `ByVal` for the `hPrinter` and `Level` parameters.

`Public Declare Function StartDocPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias "StartDocPrinterA" (ByVal hPrinter As Long, ByVal Level As Long, dDocInfo As DOCINFO) As Long`

Comment: Now, I can just figure out how to print to 'Adobe PDF'.

Answer (score -1):

Your declaration for the [DOCINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183574(v=vs.85).aspx) structure does not look correct.  It should be declared as:

```
Type DOCINFO
   cbSize As Integer
   lpszDocName As String
   lpszOutput As String
   lpszDatatype As String
   fwType As Integer
End Type
```

The cbSize should be initialized to the size of the structure in bytes, and fwType should be set to 0.

Comment: That's for GDI Printing, not [Print Spooler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145115(v=vs.85).aspx) and [DOCINFO1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162471(v=vs.85).aspx).